# Why does this templated struct with C++17 `constexpr if` fail to compile on MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

This code fails to compile on MSVC with error C2065 "'test': undeclared identifier".
Clang compiles without warnings, GCC compiles but warns with `-Wall` "warning: variable 'test' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]".
A comparison is available on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/LBQXQv).

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    constexpr auto operator()() const
    {
        if constexpr (constexpr auto test = true; test)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int> bar{};

    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

There are a number of ways to make this compile

1. Remove the template around `foo`
2. Remove the `constexpr`
3. Assign `test` outside of the `if constexpr`

   ```cpp
   constexpr auto test = true;
   if constexpr (test)
   ```

What is the reason for this compilation failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a bug for MSVC and GCC.

There is already a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/189937/vs-2017-c-compiler-bug-regarding-constexpr-if-init.html) for MSVC.

For GCC, it may be related to [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82728), and [is fixed in GCC trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/hLhY78).